# Why does Stripe support React-Native when Apple Store won't allow you to use it?

Tags: ios, react-native, stripe-payments

I am a tad frustrated as I didn't know this was a thing until I just got my app rejected today from the store. Integrating with Stripe and setting up web-hooks took a long time for me to figure out. I got it nailed down only to find out I can't use it.

Why does Stripe support react-native if you can't actually use it to get on the app stores? Is there anything I can do to salvage all my hard work? Its all done through an express API so I suppose I could use it for a web-app version, but right now I am focusing on IOS and Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple (and Google) have strict rules around what can and can't be sold in a mobile application using a third-party system instead of their IAP (in-app purchase) system.

Stripe documents this in details in their docs such as [here](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay?platform=ios#using-stripe-and-apple-pay-versus-in-app-purchases) where they explain that you can only use Stripe to sell physical goods or services (such as food delivery or club memberships).

There are lots of businesses that can offer Apple Pay in cases like this which is why Stripe offers mobile SDKs for iOS, Android and now React Native but it does come with strict restrictions enforced by Apple (and Google) in this case.